# How do I run a for loop on the command line as root in bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, sudo

I'm trying to run a simple for loop to check and display the temperature of several hard drives like so:

```
for drive in a b c d e f g; do hddtemp "/dev/sd$drive"; done
```

This works great if I su to root, but I'd like to just be able to run it or other loop type one-line commands on the command line if possible where sudo might be required.
If I try

```
sudo for drive in a b c d e f g; do hddtemp "/dev/sd$drive"; done;
```

I get this error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Same error as above if I omit the final `;` (semicolon)

Enclosing the command in `"` (double quotes) gives this result:

> sudo: for drive in a b c d e f g; do hddtemp /dev/sdg; done: command
>   not found

Enclosing the command in back-ticks (`` ` ``)

```
sudo "`for drive in a b c d e f g; do hddtemp "/dev/sd$drive"; done`"
```

gives an error for each instance of drive letter/spec specified:

> /dev/sda: open: Permission denied    followed by  sudo: :
>   command not found

Is it possible to run a for (or other loop) command as a command line one-liner sudo'ing or otherwise using my root credentials in bash?

Ubuntu linux 16.04LTS  /  GNU bash 4.3.46(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put `sudo` before the `for` loop. The following works fine.

```
for drive in {a..g}; do sudo hddtemp "/dev/sd$drive"; done
```

Comment: Even better use `/dev/sd?`

Comment: Looks short and like it would extend to this sort of loop running a sudo command most generally, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest:

```
for drive in a b c d e f g; do sudo hddtemp "/dev/sd$drive"; done
```

or

```
sudo bash -c 'for drive in a b c d e f g; do hddtemp "/dev/sd$drive"; done'
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers tell you how to fix your problem of looping over a command with sudo. You don't actually need a loop, though, as `hddtemp` apparently can take multiple arguments, so you could just do

```
sudo hddtemp /dev/sd{a,b,c,d,e,f,g}
```

(no quotes – they would prevent brace expansion), which expands to

```
sudo hddtemp /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf /dev/sdg
```

If your drives are really called exactly that, you can shorten to

```
sudo hddtemp /dev/sd{a..g}
```

Comment: That works well, thanks for the information / method.  It was interesting to find out how to iterate a sudo command, too.